# WP media upload issues

Tags: uploads, media

I've come across a lot of people facing this issue that was eventually solved by  file permission.

I'm getting this error:

> The uploaded file could not be moved to
>   wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2019/11.

While I've tried even with `chmod -r 777` in my wp-content/uploads, it is still returning the same error.

I've also added in my wp-config

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php' );
```

But nothing seems to work.

Comment: What kind of upload directory structure do you have? Usually it’s like ’uploads/YEAR/MONTH/’ if you have the store in years/month folders option.

Answer (score 0):

You could look here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/wordpress-the-uploaded-file-could-not-be-moved-to-wp-content-uploads for some good answers.